# Erase RAM while device is on

Tags: forensics, memory, deletion

Is there anyway to get rid of the data in RAM without powering off the system?  or better to say how we can reduce the chance of getting meaning full information from the volatile memory while the system still is on?

Comment: simply fill up the ram with new data that you need not hide.

Comment: Which OS? Are you the developer of the application you're trying to erase the memory contents of?

Comment: @Polynomial The OS is not the matter, I can do it either on Windows or Linux. This is part of university project, in which I need to develop a program to erase the memory contents. I have to make sure that whole data are deleted from the RAM not data of a specific application.

Comment: @dandavis Do you have any efficient suggestion for filling the RAM, is there any specific function for this?

Comment: @Mah The problem is highly OS-specific because "unused" has different meanings in every operating system. In general no OS will leave available RAM completely empty because it's inefficient not to use it as disk cache. Blindly overwriting this is very likely to cause a crash or corrupted system stage. The only safe way to wipe **all** RAM is to reboot - even if you bring your system down to a minimal state with only your "clear RAM" code running, you still need that "clear RAM" code to be in memory during that process.

Comment: @Mah The other way to go is to not delete contents from RAM, but encrypt it instead. [TRESOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRESOR) is a Linux patch that attempts to implement such functionality, hiding key material in CPU debug registers. It doesn't protect against RAM access from a running system, but it helps protect against cold boot attacks.

Comment: @mah Ok? That is not relevant here.

Comment: Since you mention that this is a university project, my guess is that you've either misunderstood what you're being asked to do, or have been given a fundamentally impossible challenge with some ulterior motive (e.g. getting you to understand why it is impossible). "Delete all data from RAM without shutting down" is not something you can do while preserving system state in any useful or recoverable way. I suggest you clarify the requirements with your lecturer.

Comment: @Polynomial Thanks. I have already checked the encryption solution, but let's say we don't want to go that way and we have a server which we cannot turn off as well. But, we are looking for a solution to make sure without harming normal system process, all the data (or better to say the most possible data) are wiped out, masked or even noised after performing that kind of deletion.

Comment: @Polynomial So I'm not intended to delete everything I want to reduce the chance of extracting sensitive data from the RAM as much as possible. this can be done by adding noise or at least trying to fill up some part of memories. Means that I am looking for the best possible soft solution for this like using explicit_bzero().

Comment: @Mah You could probably patch the `munmap` syscall in Linux to force each page to be zeroed when the original mapping was marked as `MAP_ANONYMOUS` (i.e. not a file-backed mapping).

Comment: @mah: utilities that can do a checkerboard or walking bit RAM test would work, as would a ram disk that you copy bland media into. just opening a ton of tabs in chrome fills it up well...

Comment: OP needs to pay attention. His question has been answered.

Answer (score -1):

Since you do not mention OS:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bzero.3.html - it's fairly ubiquitous.

Use explicit_bzero() to avoid the compiler accidentally trimming away your wipe for whatever reason. If you kill off the sensitive program and fork a few processes that each gobble say, 512M, you have achieved what you need. Remember to unmount swap first - even before running your sensitive program.

You can set the children to each chunk as much memory as you like. The reaper will clean them up when they hit memory limits.